Converting black and white pixel raster to lines or polygons
I have a black and white bitmap pixel image (gif) of historical election precincts in Germany. I don't know the coordinate system, but EPSG:3035 is coming relatively close.
But even if we just assume that CSR: How can I convert the pixel graphic to polygons or lines?
I read about GRASS's r.thin and r.to.vect but neither of them did what I expected. Instead it just converted the lines to areas where the black was one area and the white another.
GDAL polygonize did the same.
Do you have any additional ideas how to go about this? This is one of the images:


After @Bera’s comment, this works quite well!
I did the following to end up with the result below:

Georeference image with lots of points and Polyominal 2 and resampling Bilinear
GDAL Translate with nodata value 251.0 (white pixel value)
r.thin with 75 iterations
r.to.vect with output type line
Polygonize

I went back between steps 3 and 4 and manually fixed some lines.

